# Visa rejection by Turkish consulate in India

Tags: visa-refusals, turkey

I recently applied for Turkey touristic sticker visa and got rejected from Mumbai consulate. I got informed from gateway that I can re-apply only after 6 months. Can I apply for any other visas rather than touristic like business visa before this waiting period?

Comment: Would you actually be traveling to Turkey for business? It would be extremely suspicious to apply for a tourist visa, be rejected, and then suddenly turn around and say "ok I want to go for a business trip instead." It makes you look desperate to get a visa and like you're changing your story, and neither of those are good things when you've already had one application denied.

Comment: Did you have to state your occupation when you applied for the tourist visa? Apart from the risks surrounding a sudden change of story regarding the purpose of your trip, you should consider what inconsistencies a change of application type might throw up. If you genuinely want to visit as a tourist, best to wait and address any reason(s) given for the refusal meanwhile